# QGIS geolocate a DBF file with another point layer by matching field

Tags: qgis, geolocation

I have a DBF table and a SHP with points. I want to geolocate the DBF file using the points layer. Both match in a field called "unificationstring".

I know how to do it in postgis but how can this be done in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the two files
2. Go to *Vector Layer Properties* on the Shapefile
3. Click *Joins* > *+*
4. Choose the second (dbf) layer as *Join Layer*
5. Choose the appropriate fields to join on (unificationstring in both comboboxes)
6. Optional: Save the shapefile to a new one which will have the joined attributes attached.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I thought of the same solution but I have one problem with this solution. I have several records in the dbf that have the same unificationstring. If I use the joining method from SHP->DBF only the first unificationstring found in the DBF is joined. Due to this, some DBF records result not being joined. If i try to join DBF->SHP the joining is not happening...(I guess because it has no geometry field?)